# error message could not find function "paste0" –

Tags: r

I am getting an error message when I execute the below code

```
datacfs_date$FeedbackMonth <- paste0(year(datacfs_date$FeedbackDate),
                                     "-M", month(da‌​tacfs_date$FeedbackDate)) 

Error in eval.with.vis(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "paste0".
```

Do I need to import some package? Kindly assist

Comment: No package required, `paste` is from base. Try something simple like `paste(1:4, "a"); paste0(1:4, "a");` Will that work? The last character in `paste0` is zero, not big O, check that as well.

Comment: What version of R do you run? I have also had problems with not finding `paste0` previously, and suspect that it could have been missing in a particular short-lived version of R.

Comment: I am running R version 2.14.2 (2012-02-29)

Comment: The function `paste0` was introduced to base R in version 2.15.0 ([NEWS](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/2.15.0/NEWS.R-2.15.0.html)).  Upgrade your version, or use `paste(..., sep="")`

Comment: i have just started learning R. how do i use  paste(..., sep="") for code below  --> datacfs_date$FeedbackMonth <- paste0(year(datacfs_date$FeedbackDate),
                                     "-M", month(da‌​tacfs_date$FeedbackDate))

Comment: `paste(year(datacfs_date$FeedbackDate), "-M", month(datacfs_date$FeedbackDate), sep="")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `paste0()` was introduced in R version 2.15.0 - so your easiest option is to upgrade your version.

Otherwise use the original `paste()`, like this:

```
paste(year(datacfs_date$FeedbackDate), "-M", month(da‌​tacfs_date$FeedbackDate),
      sep="")
```

---

As Richie Cotton points out, you can also define your own `paste0` function:

```
paste0 <- function(..., collapse = NULL) {
    paste(..., sep = "", collapse = collapse)
}
```

Comment: Or you could define `paste0 <- function(..., collapse = NULL) paste(..., sep = "", collapse = collapse)`.

Comment: Not sure it is paste or something that i missing ... i am gettig an error message > datacfs_date$FeedbackMonth<-paste(year(datacfs_date$FeedbackDate), "-M", month(datacfs_date$FeedbackDate),sep="") 


Error in paste(year(datacfs_date$FeedbackDate), "-M", month(datacfs_date$FeedbackDate),  :    could not find function "year"

Comment: AFAIK, there is no function `year()` in base R.  Try using the package `lubridate` to work with dates and times.